# converting some columns in groupby to multilevel in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a groupby object that looks like the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user1':[2,4,21,21],'user2':[6,13,76,76],'param1':[0,2,0,1],'param2':['x','a','a','d'],'count':[1
,3,2,1]}, columns=['user1','user2','param1','param2','count'])
df = df.set_index(['user1','user2','param1','param2'])
```

which gives

```
                           count
user1 user2 param1 param2
2     6     0      x           1
4     13    2      a           3
21    76    0      a           2
            1      d           1
```

I want to have something like this:

```
param1      0             1      2
param2      a      x      d      a
user1 user2 
2     6     0      1      0      0
4     13    0      0      0      3
21    76    2      0      1      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with sorting columns by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df['count'].unstack([2,3], fill_value=0).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
param1       0     1  2
param2       a  x  d  a
user1 user2            
2     6      0  1  0  0
4     13     0  0  0  3
21    76     2  0  1  0
```